# How to keep pagination data during navigations in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, navigation

I have an application that has a list and details page. In the list page, the table has paging feature and there is also a search box that filters the list items. When clicking on an item in the list it opens details of the related record. I am wondering what is a proper way to keep the paging and filter parameters of the list page when I navigate to details page and then use these parameters when come back to this list page. I meant that, the user in on the 3rd page of the list and then click details icon of a record. then opens details page and later click back button on that page. I want the user can navigate to the 3rd page again by getting the parameter values that he sent before. If I can get these values the rest would be ok of course.

Should I use `NavigationExtras` or etc for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of implementing such functionality. In general, you need to save the last search state (search value, page, search results, etc.) somewhere during the list component OnDestroy and then use them in OnInit hook of the list component. Here's an example of using service:

**list component**

```
constructor(private preserveSearch: PreserveSearchService){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.recoverLastSearchValue();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.preserveSearch.searchState = {
        searchValue: this.searchControl.value,
        results: this.data,
        resultsLength: this.resultsLength,
    };
}

recoverLastSearchValue() {
    const lastSearch = this.preserveSearch.searchState;
    if (lastSearch) {
        this.searchControl.setValue(lastSearch.searchValue, {
            emitEvent: false,
            emitModelToViewChange: false,
        });
        this.data = lastSearch.results;
        this.resultsLength = lastSearch.resultsLength;
    }
}
```

**search state service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { SearchResultsItem } from "app/_models/search";

interface PreservedSearchState {
    searchValue: string;
    results: SearchResultsItem[];
    resultsLength: number;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class PreserveSearchService {
    private lastSearch: PreservedSearchState;

    get searchState(): PreservedSearchState {
        return this.lastSearch;
    }

    set searchState(lastSearch: PreservedSearchState) {
        this.lastSearch = lastSearch;
    }

    constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. What if I would like to use a class instead of `PreserveSearchService`? I mean that there s already a class for similar approaches and I want to move the logic in `PreserveSearchService` to that class.

Comment: The **second** question is that, is it logical to pass the search parameters via route and then when returning to this page retrieve them in navigation parameters?

Comment: sure you can add the logic of `PreserveSearchService` wherever you want. it's just an example.
Regarding the usage of query parameters - it's a classic approach for pagination. It's the easiest way for providing links like _myshop.com/products?page=2&searchTerm=something_ That way your search terms and pagination setup are persistent after reload, you can share such links, it's great for SEO support in paginated lists, etc.

Comment: I tried to use via class, but unfortunately not worked.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? How did you implement it there?

Comment: I create `PreserveSearchService` (I converted t to a class) instance using `new` and when coming back to the list page again, it is created again and then I cannot access the previously set values. On the other hand, it is destroyed when navigating details page and I think I have to create its instance when comimng back to the list page.